# AEM: URL Shortening for assets

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, aem, sling, url-shortener

I am new to AEM rewrite rules. I have two URLs

1. /content/dam/app/document/folder/filename.docx
2. /document/folder/filename or /document/filename

I want to shorten the first URL to second URL using Rewrite Rules in Apache. But am not exactly sure on how to do it. Is there any solution to this?

So far I have written
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/document/.*
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.docx

This appends the extension at the end but /content/dam/app/ needs to be appended

Comment: Yes, it's much like shortening page paths, a matter of finding the right regular expression. You could also ensure there's a proper config for Sling mapping so that AEM renders URLs matching the ones you want to resolve here. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can take a look at the archetype example: https://github.com/adobe/aem-project-archetype/blob/develop/src/main/archetype/dispatcher.cloud/src/conf.d/rewrites/rewrite.rules#L24 this gives you an opportunity to write something like `RewriteRule ^/document/folder/filename$  /content/dam/app/document/folder/filename.docx [PT,L]` and then build generalization on top of that.